# »im Dunklen tappen« vs »im Dunkeln tappen«: What is the difference?

Tags: declension

According to the inflection chart of the adjective *dunkel*, its neuter dative form for the weak inflection is *dunk**le**n*. But both of the following phrases seem to be used. I wonder what is the difference between the two. Does it come down to a personal preference?

> im Dunk**le**n tappen
>
> im Dunk**el**n tappen

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have:

1. **im Dunkel**: This is the noun *Dunkel* (elevated form of *Dunkelheit*).
2. **im Dunklen**: This is the nominalized form of the adjective *dunkel*.
3. **im Dunkeln**: This is probably a set expression, alternative to 2. It might as well be an alternative (archaic?) dative of *Dunkel*. 
   The [Duden](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/dunkel) lists this phrase only with the adjective, not with the noun.

I think:

- **im Dunklen** is mandatory when talking about beer or something else named **das Dunkle**.
- **im Dunkeln** is mandatory (at least: good style) when it means the unknown, obfuscated.
- Meaning the absence of light, both forms seem appropriate. Though **im Dunkeln** sounds much more idiomatic to me, **im Dunklen** is still fine if you want to emphasize, that you do not use it figuratively:

> - Die Polizei tappt im Dunkeln.
> - Er tappt im Dunklen nach der Taschenlampe.

Answer (score 1):

Those are different words:

- **das Dunkle**
  This is a nominalized adjective, derived from the adjective *dunkel*. In English it is "the dark".

  > **Das Dunkle** schmeckt mehr nach Malz als **das Helle**.
  >   **The dark** tastes more like malt than **the light**.

  Note, that in English nominalized adjective are very rare, so in the English translation of my example *dark* and *light* still are adjectives, because they both will be interpreted as attributes of the omitted noun "*beer*". But in German »das Dunkle« and »das Helle« will be understood as nouns, and this also is the reason why you have to write them capitalized. In English you can find nominalized adjectives in phrases like »the poor and the rich«.

  Note, that nominalized adjectives (*das Große*) and nominalized verbs (*das Gehen*) are nouns (with all rights and obligations of nouns). They are not adjectives/verbs!
- **das Dunkel**
  This is a "normal" noun, not a nominalized adjective. Etymological it also evolved from *dunkel*, but grammatically it is an independent word. In English it is "the darkness".

  > Siegfried reitet in **das Dunkel**.
  >   Siegfried is riding into **the darkness**.

If you tap in the dark, it doesn't matter much if you mean "tap in the dark" or "tap in the darkness". It's quite the same.

Comment: I think this is not correct. "Im Dunkeln" isn't derived from "das Dunkel". It would have to be "im Dunkel" in the Dativ case.